# Export value in a excel file using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

How can i export a result set from a query command into a excel file in SSIS package?

One main problem is the excel datasheet header name ever month will change.

like in FEB month the excel file header will be

```
   Name,Address,FEB,JAN,DEC......
```

In MAR month the excel file header will change and it will became

```
   Name,Address,MAR,FEB,JAN,DEC......
```

how can i do this??

Comment: How does the columns end. Is there a specific count for columns.
FEB,JAN,DEC.. How far this goes?. Only till DEC, or NOV?

Comment: 5 or 6 latest month it showed

Comment: And what is the destination table column names??
Month 1, month 2 ..Month 6?

Comment: no it will feb14,jan14,dec13 like this

Comment: So every month, the destination table will be different?

Comment: yeah the destination table col name will change every month.

Comment: A package in SSIS will have to be updated every time the metadata (e.g. column names) change. Is there no possibility of keeping the excel columns constant and for example change them in code to what it needs to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way without getting your hands dirty and tampering with Interop.Excel.

Here's how:

1. Use e.g. Exec SQL Task to stuff your dataset into an object variable
2. Use Script Task to utilize Interop.Excel to programmatically access your XLS, wipe it out, write new data from the mentioned variable and close it. Btw, this is where you handle your dynamic set of columns.

It's kinda ugly, but you'll get your work done.

For the example, see [this](http://sqlage.blogspot.com/2013/12/ssis-create-excel-file-dynamically-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go through the given way of doing this.

**prerequesite**

```
1.  I assume that the Excel files come at same location with names as follow.
        JAN14
        FEB14
        MAR14
2.  JAN14 Columns be
        Name,Address,JAN14,DEC14,NOV14
    FEB14 Coulmns be
        Name,Address,FEB14,JAN14,DEC14
```

**Logic used**

1. Load all the excel sheets to a stage table.
2. And then dynamically load each set of data from this stage table to appropriate tables.

---

File location
[image]

I created A stage table, 2 tables for each excel. In your case, assume that an automated system takes care of creating these tables.

```
Create table Stg
(F1 varchar(50), 
F2 varchar(50), 
F3 varchar(255),
F4 varchar(255),
F5 varchar(255),
src varchar(50))

Create table Jan14
(Name varchar(50), 
Address varchar(50), 
Jan14 varchar(255),
Dec13 varchar(255),
Nov13 varchar(255))

Create table Feb14
(Name varchar(50), 
Address varchar(50), 
Feb14 varchar(255), 
Jan14 varchar(255),
Dec13 varchar(255))
```

SSIS package

[image]

Excel source connection be like this

[image]

After the For-each loop execution, The **Src** data will be like this

```
Select * from Stg
```

[image]

The last sql task content is as follows.

```
Declare @a int = (Select COUNT(Distinct Src) from Stg)

Declare @b table (id int identity(1,1),Src varchar(50))
Insert into @b 
Select Distinct Src from Stg

Declare @c int = 1,@d varchar(max)

While @c <= @a
Begin
    Set @d = 'Insert into ' + (select Src From @b Where id = @c) 
                            + ' Select F1,F2,F3,F4,F5 FROM Stg WHERE Src =''' + 
                            (select Src From @b Where id = @c) + ''' AND F1 != ''Name'''
    Set @c = @c + 1
    Exec(@d)
End
```

At the end of the package execution, I got the results as follows.

```
Select * from [dbo].[Jan14]
Select * from  [dbo].[Feb14]
```

[image]

Some of the constraints followed here are just for convenience, like excel name is same as third column of excel, etc.
I hope we can achieve your desired result with the same kind of code.